# C# XML comments - build a list

Tags: c#, xml-comments

I am trying to build a list for my XML comments on my C# method.

I am using the following document, however the list implementation in this does not work for me. I am using visual studio 2008 and .net 3.5.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx

How do I build a list using XML comments in C#?

Here is my current XML code. The para tag works fine, however no list is being generated.

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Populates an entity from the database.
    /// <para />
    /// <list type="table">
    /// <listheader>
    /// <term>This method contains assumptions in the implementation of the entity:</term>
    /// </listheader>
    /// <item><term>Given the entity name [name]Entity (eg. [User]Entity is User), there is an
    /// appropriate stored procedure created: dbo.sp[name]View (eg. dbo.spUserView).
    /// <para />
    /// The structure of the stored procedure must adhere to design principles to correctly
    /// load the data into the objects.
    /// <para />
    /// See documentation on implementation of stored procedures if you are unsure of any details.
    /// </term>
    /// </item>
    /// </list>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
```

Comment: Have you enabled 'Generate XML Comments' in the appropriate projects' options?

Comment: Only list doesn't work? Could you post your code for this?

Comment: @Hun1Ahpu - See updated code. @Alex, yep all boxes checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove para tag inside your list.